# How to change link based on cookie?

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to change the link of a navigation button based on the URL entered.

For ex:

There is a button I want to change link based on the URL entered. Suppose the link of the button is 123.com on the website xyz.com. But if someone enters the URL: xyz.com/1, then I want the button to have the link 123.com/1

Comment: And Java is tagged because??

Comment: Corrected it. Sorry!

Comment: Be specific, and show us what you've tried - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice

Comment: Title has a keyword 'Cookie' which you didn't use inside the post , tags have php,html and css which don't have any relation with the post . Please be more specific and describe your issue in a proper way . Show us what you've tried .

Answer (score 0):

```js
var Loc=window.location.href;
var ReLoc="https://123.com"
var n=Loc.replace(/(((https:\/\/)|(http:\/\/))((\w*)|(\d*)).((\w{3,4})|(\d{3,4})))/g,"");
var NewLoc=ReLoc+n;
console.log("Current Local: "+ Loc);
console.log("New Local: "+ NewLoc);
```